# Loop through specific field in Array

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, array

I am looping through an array but it is looping through each field of the record.  So the record has 4 fields so its looping 4 times for each record.  I need all of the fields because I will use them to populate a data table but I want to only iterate through each record based on a single field on the record. I can see all of the fields and their values in the 'Object.values(rec)'.  But I just want to iterate through the customSearchField__c of each record

```
 for (let rec of this.originalRecords) {
     let valuesArray = Object.values(rec);  
        for (let val of valuesArray) {
            console.log('val is ' + val);
            let strVal = String(val);
            if (strVal) {
               let lowerSearchKey = searchKey.toLowerCase();
               let lowerstrVal = strVal.toLowerCase();
                   if (lowerstrVal.includes(lowerSearchKey)) {
                      searchRecords.push(rec);
                      break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cut quite a bit out I think - there is no need to iterate the object.

Just grab the field you want and check it's value:

```
for (let rec of this.originalRecords) {
     
     const searchField = rec['customSearchField__c'];
     
     if (searchField) {
        let lowerSearchKey = searchKey.toLowerCase();
        let lowersearchField = searchField.toLowerCase();
            if (lowersearchField.includes(lowerSearchKey)) {
               searchRecords.push(rec);
               break;
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @casper Harmer.  I will give this a try.    But I will still be able to access all of the fields of the records that match correct?   I want to populate a data table with the matching records.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. You could try adding a small sample of the data you are receiving to the question, but if it's just sObjects from a query, this should work.

Comment: Just a note that 'break' needs to be removed for the above code to work.